# How to display columns having same value?

Tags: sql

consider the following table

```
id   Part_no  cust.  work_order
1    abc      xyz    111
2    abc      xyz    123
3    abc      xyz    121
4    qqq      xyz    222
```

Now when I enter a particular work order I want the following display.

```
part_no   cust   work_order
abc       xyz     111
abc       xyz     123
abc       xyz     121
```

Comment: do you mean, if you enter 111 for the work_order, you want the other columns to come up?  Because that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Which db you use ... oracle, mysql ,  sqlserver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wyatt Shipman's answer should work. Here's another way to do it:

```
select a.part_no, a.cust, a.work_order from thetable as a
inner join thetable as b on a.part_no = b.part_no
where a.work_order = 111;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/03923/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql You can force a specific order by based an value for a fields

```
select part_no, cust, work_order
from your_table 
where part_no = 'abc' 
order by  FIELD(work_order,111,123,121);
```

for Oracle yuo can use decode

```
 select part_no, cust, work_order
from your_table 
where part_no = 'abc' 
order by  decode(work_order,111,1, 123,2,121,3);
```

*(could  be  doesn't make sense but you can do it)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select query to create a list like below

```
SELECT Part_No, Cust, Work_Order
FROM tblA a
WHERE a.Part_No in (SELECT ai.Part_No from tblA ai where a.workorder=111)
```